# Bootstrap Smaller Navbar Collapse Width

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i have a problem i was searching all day for answer and did't find it.
The code:

```
<div class="visible-xs navbar navbar-ti navbar-fixed-top ">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle pull-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger white"></span>
      </button>
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed pull-right">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search white"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="wheretobuy.aspx"  style="color:#fff;" >Where to Buy</a></li>
        <li><a href="cookware.aspx" style="color:#fff;" >Cookware Sets</a></li>
        <li><a href="registration.aspx"  style="color:#fff;" >Register Product</a></li>
        <li><a href="qualitystandards.aspx"  style="color:#fff;" >Quality Standards</a></li>
        <li><a href="customerreviews.aspx"  style="color:#fff;" >Customer Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="rvinfo.aspx"style="color:#fff;" >RV Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="marineinfo.aspx"  style="color:#fff;" >Marine Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.aspx"  style="color:#fff;" >About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.aspx"  style="color:#fff;" >Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i added to bootstrap.css :

```
.white {
color: #fff !important; }.navbar-ti {
background-color:#200c03;}
```

[image]

I need to set width of collapsed nav like on picture and i wanna remove the line that arrow is pointing to . :)

i use bootstrap 3.4 and i did't change anything to bootstrap.css just added some classes. Can someone help me ?

P.S Sorry for bad English :) .

Comment: No1 know how to resize collapsed menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That horizontal line is being produced by the `box-shadow` property set on the `.navbar-collapse` element. In your bootstrap.css add the following rule:

```
.navbar-collapse {  
  box-shadow: 0 0 0; // remove box-shadow
}
```